# How to use react-native -maps in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I try to use `react-native-maps`. I tried like this :*

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView style={styles.map}
             region={{
               latitude: this.state.latitude,
               longitude:this.state.longitude,
               latitudeDelta:0.1,
               longitudeDelta:0.1, 
             }}

          >
            <Marker
              coordinate= {{
                latitude: 38.41885,
                longitude: 27.12872,
              }}
              title={'my marker'}
              description={'test'}
            />


        </MapView>
      </View>
```

however when I start app, app close immediately. I couldn understand why it close ?

Comment: Try to check all about the installation, especially in `Android Manifest.xml` the `apiKey`. Or try to uninstall the app, the re-run it.

Comment: I did it but it still same

Comment: Are you sure that adding this code only your app crashes ? Try removing the code and check if app is working or not.

Comment: When I remove package of react-native-maps it is working, Otherwise it is not. I did what they say here  :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps but still closing app

Comment: Do you enable the Google Map? and the API Key?

Comment: I added this android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="apı-key"/> to androidManifest.xml

Comment: You should enable the Google Map API in Google API Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if it does not work check your Android Emulator if it has a Google Play Services.

```
compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
 exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
 exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
```

For addition, add this.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="yourApiKey"
  />
```

Add the apiKey, after this code:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
```

So it should be like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="yourAPIkey"
  />
```

Comment: Very grateful to help.